# How to avoid this error: #TOCHECK : why got string instend of dict in python2.6 OpenERP

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I am new to python and OpenERP and I apologise if my question is inconvenient. But I am trying to add a control that check if a field is empty, but I am getting this error:

```
`if isinstance(res2[record['id']], str): res2[record['id']] = eval(res2[record['id']]) #TOCHECK : why got string instend of dict in python2.6`
```

Here is my function in hr_employee class:

```
  def _sum_of_fields(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
         res = {}
         for employee_job in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if (employee_job.job_id == True):
               for total in self.pool.get('hr.job').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                   res[total.id] = {
                   'sum': total.number_a + total.number_b,
                   }
            else: {
               'sum' : 0.00,
            }         
         return res
```

Please could you help me? What the problem could be? Is my function OK? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem was at the part:

```
else: {
               'sum' : 0.00,
            }
```

In order to work correctly you should do it in that way:

```
else: 
               for total in self.pool.get('hr.job').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                   res[total.id] = {
                   'sum': 0.00,
            }
```

It works for me now. Also you should use this, to test if the field is empty or not(not the one in the code above) :

```
if empjob.job_id.id:
```

Hope this helps you